# How can I access the web element present from the "Cänvas Id" in a html page?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium3 webdriver to automate a html page which has many click buttons
I am not able to access these buttons while the entire page is shown as canvas element.
I am unable to proceed now,it would be great if anyone shares any solution.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

canvas element are parts of iframe in most of the cases. So, find the iframe element and then find the canvas id. :
Code may look like this:

```
WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.name("iframe Name"));
 driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
 WebElement canvasId = driver.findElement(By.id("Canvas Id"));
```